# How opencv use openmp thread to get performance?

Tags: c++, opencv, openmp

I have installed OpenCV 2.4.13  -D WITH_OPENMP=ON (openmp enable). I want to know  built-in functions provided by opencv that use OPENMP so I can show some performance between with openmp and without openmp enabled version.
Do I need to change my openCV program to run with openmp?
I did not find any example program that shows how Opencv use openmp.

Comment: probably you can  search the opencv source code for openmp pragmas

Comment: `grep -R '#pragma omp'` in the root of the OpenCV source tree should do the trick.

Comment: Thanxs .. I found '# pragma omp'  in   modules/contrib/src/spinimages.cpp: file.  in which computeSpinImages() function use   ' #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthreads)' .  but how I use this in our openCv program .

Comment: these lines should automatically be active if openCV was compiled successfully with WITH_OPENMP=ON. In your program print the result of getBuildInformation() and find whether openMP is used in your build.